# Why my object isn't equal Object? How to check if var is a Object?

Tags: javascript, object

I'm trying to detect is my variable is object.

I have that code:

```
var obj = {
    'propA': 'a',
        'propB': {
        'underB': 'underBB',
            'underB2': 'underBB2'
    }
};
```

now when I checking: `obj === Object` I'm getting false even if when I type obj in console I see it's object:

```
Object {propA: "a", propB: Object}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Mkg3w/)**

### Questions:

- How I can check if obj is a Object?
- Why when I try compare my var and Object I'm getting **false**?

Comment: I'm 99.999% sure this question has been asked here before. Now to find it...

Comment: @j08691 I know, but I've trying to find without success. I always searching before post question

Comment: For starters, `Object` is a `function`...

Comment: @acdcjunior Are you sure? I was always think that `function` is a `Object`?

Comment: `console.debug(Object); console.debug(typeof Object);` should show you the way, padawan :)

Comment: is it allowed to put in a comment that the question is just plain  stupid ?

Comment: @VincentPiel No, but it's too late now ; ).

Comment: minuses for asking? or the asnwer was too easy for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
if(typeof obj == 'object')
```

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

This will also return true if obj is an array so sometimes its good to use [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) to make sure its an object of the 'type' you want.

Comment: Well you are checking type so I would say a type check is the best way yes.

Comment: Also see instanceof as mentioned in this answer and the other answer when you want to get specific (i.e checking the variables constructor)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `instance of` to determine type of an object.try this :

```
console.log(obj instanceof Object);
```

Besides, you are comparing object instance with a contractor(function) with `===` operator.this will always be false.